# File IO sync in java 5

Tags: java, io, synchronization

I have a job which will be writing huge amount of data in a csv file in directory A. Then there is another job will be reading the file from directory A after some time. The process which will be writing runs once a day. the process will be reading runs multiple times a day.

I will be first writing the file to a temporary folder say dir_timestamp. Once completed that file will be moved to directory. Now the question is

What if while the file is being moved to the directory, the other process comes and tries to read it? The way it will be reading it would be

```
File dir = new File (path_to_dir);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (File f : files)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

- Would a partial written file visible to process 2 ?
- If yes, then would it be fine if I copy the file to directory with some name without any extension and add a filter while reading that there has to be some extension (.csv probably) ? and once copied, i can rename it with extension ?
- Even if I do the renaming stuff, Java `File.Rename()` is actually used for moving the file too. Would underlying java copying the file from scratch while renaming or what ?

Comment: If you are reading the file, the java program has a "lock" on it and you won't be able to move/delete it. If you start moving it, then you wont hand a handle to it available.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: that would only be true on Windows. Unix-like OSes will happily allow the file to be moved and/or deleted even when it is open...

Comment: @thkala Will the OS still give you all the bytes or cut you off?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - On UNIX, move is an atomic operation that takes place in the directory not in the file. Not a single byte is moved in the file. (Unless, of course, it is moved to a different filesystem. But still, the source is not touched, until all that have it open close it.

Comment: so would it safe to say that on Windows, I wouldn't be allowed to get a handle while file is being moved and on Unix, the move operation by itself is atomic ?